# what's the hotkey to select folder in 'save as' box?

Tags: windows

While in daily operation, I need to download many files from emails,or similar source, or save  file in MS word/excel, and i need to select the source folder in the address bar on the top of the dialogue box. Now i have to click many times to select the folder, I prefer to do it with keyboard shortcut, how ?

Comment: What does any of this mean? Potentially if you always save to a single folder, you could use AutoHotKey to paste a predefined string (the path) into the filename box?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you want to know the keyboard shortcut to directly jump to the address bar/folder location in the Save As dialog, right?

[image: SaveAs]

Just press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (works in English language Windows).

Comment: you ar correct, i am using CN version window XP, and it wont' work what shall i do?and plus, is there a way to jump to and activate the 'recent' or 'desktop' button which is on the left of the dialogue box?

Comment: Alt+D is the keyboard shortcut to jump to the address bar even in browsers. I have no idea about Chinese versions of the OS, but you should be able to figure out the equivalent key with a little trial and error.